# twitter boostrap tooltip on joomla 1.5

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla1.5, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am having an issue displaying the tooltip only on my joomla 1.5 template (yes I know I should upgrade to a newer version of joomla, but unfortunately this option is not available in the moment)
basically the code use is as getbootstrap website

```
  <button title="" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

and the js used

```
<script>
$(function () { jQuery("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
</script>
```

This works fine in any template but when is added into joomla I get the following error on the jquery.min.js :TypeError : e is undefined 
Here's the image of the firebug console

[image]

Comment: jquery and bootstrap versions used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the $ operator is already used by mootools. To be jQuery safe use the following code

```
<script>
    var myjQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
    myjQuery(document).ready(function () {
        myjQuery("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, with your option the error doesnt show up anymore. But the tooltip still doesnt show up, thanks

Comment: For a test I would give the button an id and change the selector to #myButton to make sure the selector is not a problem.

Comment: Hi I did that and it didnt worked, but I also realise that if i try to use something like jquery ui it doesnt work as well, for instance i add the datepicker and it didnt display, i test the tenplate copying everything and saving it into my localhost and deleteing all of the <?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/ and it works fine in my localhost